# How to write exceptions or something like that in NSIS with the Zipdll plugin?

Tags: nsis

May somebody knows how to write `IfErrors` or something like that for Zipdll plugin.

`ZipDLL::extractall "c:\test.zip" "c:\output"` when for example you don't have enough space, or haven't got permission, does zipdll have a exit code or some way of checking for errors?

Comment: Or the zipdll's  errorlevel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From its [wiki page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ZipDLL_plug-in):

> On Success, the string "success" is on top of the stack, else an error
>   message.

```
ZipDLL::extractall "c:\test.zip" "c:\output"
Pop $0
;$0 is now "success" or a error message...
```